# if 3 values are same then 2 not show how to possible in php

Tags: php

**My First Value:**

```
 $rowPro['products_price2]
```

**My Second Value:**

```
 $rowPro['products_price']
```

**My ThirdValue:**

```
 $rowPro['special_price']
```

if that 3 value are same then i just want Second Value.....[Look In this Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2645.jpg)]
[image]

Comment: `if($rowPro['products_price'] == $rowPro['products_price'])
    {
        if($rowPro['special_price'] == $rowPro['products_price'])
            echo $rowPro['products_price'];
    }`

Comment: both first n second value is same coz, variables r same.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($rowPro['products_price'] == $rowPro['products_price2'] && $rowPro['special_price'] == $rowPro['products_price2']) {$myFinalPrice= $rowPro['products_price2'];}
```

Note that I'm assuming all three values are unique.

Comment: product price will always be equal to product price so does special price.

Comment: I assume the OP wanted the second value to be different than first value.  If not the case then you are correct.

Comment: question requires more clarity, but your answer always echo only 1 value, coz your condition is like that.

Comment: arrrggg sorry... overlooked my copy/paste. fixed.